# Using MDT and adding Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribution Packages

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, wds, mdt

I've been using WDS to deply default images for awhile and I just learned about MDT. I am at the point of adding applications. I want to include all the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005-2010 x86/x64. However, I currently have them in .exe from the Windows website.

I can't figure out how to add them. Do I need run them or something and then add source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to open the Deployment workbench and navigate to the applications section, from there you can add a new application which will be available to clients when the task sequence variables are being selected prior to the image being deployed.

Once there you will be asked whether you your application contains source files or not. Since this is an .EXE you won't need to select it contains source files, since all the source files will be built into the .exe, in most cases.

You would only select that the application has source files when you're using an .MSI for example, which usually has a number of other files associated to it needed to successfully complete the installation.

This setting basically tells MDT to either copy the entire source directory of application files to the Deployment share or just copy only a single file such as your .EXE.

In my experience, it's always best to opt with an .MSI over deploying a .EXE as silent install commands are not always built into the package for .EXE executables I don't believe. However .MSI packages will accept known parameters such as:

/quiet 
/passive
-norestart

As mentioned in other answers, you need to know the silent install command for installing the package if you're using a .EXE, with an .MSI you can use the standard parameters.

For example

setup.exe -S -Q

Or

Msiexec /i setup64.msi -qn -norestart

The task sequence basically runs the command lines you specify after installation of windows, just as you would if you were installing a application via the command line on a machine manually, so test prior to adding to MDT.

Answer (score 1):

We use 2010 MDT, and recently had a Microsoft consultant onsite training us.  It's really easy to add applications, you just have to add the application with source files.  You right click and add an application, but make sure to choose the option "with source files."

Also, you need only put the path to where your executable is, not the full path to the actual executable as then MDT can pick source files for x86/x64 as needed without prompting.

[This is a great step by step guide that](http://sccmavenger.com/2011/06/13/adding-applications-to-mdt-2010/) should help, but you're already on the right track.

Comment: You also need to figure out the command lines for running your installers silently.
For the VC++ redist installers version 2005 and 2008 can be installed using "vcredist_x86.exe /q /r:n" and for 2010 it's "vcredist_x86.exe /q /norestart"